# Replacing char in an array

Tags: c

I am trying to build an algorithm where i have two arrays namely

```
char cipher[MAX_CIPHER_SIZE+1]={0}, text[MAX_TEXT_SIZE+1]={0};
```

so in this case either of the arrays can be larger than the other. So using the cipher array i want to find a matching character and replace it with the next character in the cipher array. so in this case

```
  int count=0;

  for(i=0;i<=ciphercount;i++){

    for(j=0;j<=textcount;j++){
        if(cipher[i] == text[j] && cipher[count++] != '\0')
            {
                temp = cipher[count++];
                text[j] = cipher[count++];
                printf("%c\n",temp);
                temp = "";
        }
    }
}
```

unfortunately it finds and skips the assigning part. In addition if i enter i a long text it results shorten-ed text. That is excludes majority of the text.

Comment: How big is `count` at the end of your loops?

Comment: not larger than the outer loop

Comment: I assume: ```ciphercount = (sizeof cipher / sizeof cipher[0]) - 1```; and ```textcount = (sizeof text /  sizeof text[0]) - 1;``` right?

Comment: Could you give us a short example of what the two arrays might be and what result you want to get using them.

Comment: For example, if `cipher`is `{'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, ...}` and `text` is `{'a', 'a, 'a, 'c', 0}`, do you want the result to be `"bbbc"`? Or should it be `"bbba"`? Or `"bcac"`? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the purpose of your code but as -Bob__ wondering, I am worry about count.
You are increasing it all the time you access it and you never reset it to 0.
Therefore, in the worse case, at the end count is equal to ciphercount * textcount * 3 which is larger than MAX_CIPHER_SIZE+1, I guess.

Comment: Why the downvote? if both strings are exactly identical it could be perfectly fit the worst case Yardras mentioned